# Tumblr Safe Mode RSS Feeds

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

With the use of [Feedparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/feedparser) and request, I'm trying to grab an RSS feed for some tumblrs marked as explicit. An example is https://someexplicitblog.tumblr.com/rss. Is it possible to fetch them without dealing with their API? I was thinking of maybe using cookies, but the fact that they expire is a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the useragent for the request, right? if you change it to googlebot you should be able to access the feed.
here is how to change the header:
https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers
the example already has the useragent thing.
it is a little trick that works at the moment, by changing the useragent to googlebot or just including the string "googlebot" one gets access to safe mode tumblrs.